# Hiding of HTML Values through PHP

Tags: php, html

I am new to programming and I am in need of some help. I have a login page which checks if a person is a 'user' or 'admin' by checking their user_type from a MySQL database. Below is the PHP and HTML code for doing this:

```
//This is the PHP code for the login.php form
<?php
 session_start();
  include ('dbconnect.php');
   if(isset($_POST['login'])){
     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
     $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

   if(empty($username)){
     $errors[] = "Please enter your username!<br/>";
   }
   if(empty($password)){
     $errors[] = "Please enter you password!<br/>";
   }
   if(!empty($errors)){
    foreach($errors as $error){
    echo "<font color = 'red'>" . $error . "</font>";
   }
   }else{

   $query = "select * from Users
     where username = '$username'
     and password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
     $username = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     if ($username ['user_type'] == 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username['Username'];
        header('location:usermain.php');
  }else{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username['Username'];
    header('location:usermain.php');
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ?> 

//This is the HTML code for the login.php form
 <HTML>
   <div id="login_page">
    <form action = "" method = "post">
     <p> <label for = "username">Username </label> </p>
      <input type = "text" name = "username" id = "username"/>  

     <p> <label for = "password">Password </label> </p>
     <input type = "password" name = "password" id ="password"/>  

     <p> <input type = "submit" value = "Login" name = "login"/>
     <input type = "reset" value = "Refresh"/>
      </p>
     </form>
   </div>
 </HTML>
```

What I am trying to achieve is if an individual has a user_type of 'admin' they would would be able to see two links within a HTML table called 'Edit' and another link called 'Delete' under the 'Actions' column/header and if they have a user_type of 'user' I want to hide or conceal the entire 'Actions' column/header and its contents. Below is the code for the page called usermain.php after the individual has logged in:

```
 <html>
  <table>
<tr>
 <th>Imageid</th>
 <th>Image</th>
 <th>Image Description</th>
 <th>Actions</th>
</tr>

<?php   //Fetch Data form database
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['ImageID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Image']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Image_Description']; ?></td>

 //These two links which would appear under the 'Actions' table header must     
  // be hidden from a a person with the user_type of user  

 <td>
 <a href = "edit.php?pid=<?php echo $row['ImageID']; ?> ">Edit </a>       
        |
 <a href = "delete.php?pid=<?php echo $row['ImageID']; ?> ">Delete </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <?php
    }
      }else{
    ?>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">No Data Found!! </th>
</tr>
<?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
</html>
```

However when I run the page with the following code on the usermain.php page below to check the details of the current logged in user in the session I am getting the following error: Notice: "Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp64\www\foldername\page.php on line 12".

```
 <?php
  include ('dbconnect.php');
   $query = "select * from Users
     where username = '".$_SESSION['Userid']."' ";
   $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);  
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $username = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($username ['user_type'] == 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $username['Userid'];
        echo '<th>Actions</th>';
   }
  }
 ?>
```

But how can I define the $_SESSION data if the $_SESSION variable itself is suppose to retrieve the current details of the logged in individual $SESSION data? Can you please assist with where I went wrong?

Comment: not sure what you're doing here: $_SESSION['username'] = $username['Username'];

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would code the only visible to admin links.

```
<?php 
if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == admin) {
echo '<a href = "edit.php?pid=' . $row['ImageID'] . '">Edit</a> | <a href = "delete.php?pid=' . $row['ImageID'] . '">Delete </a>';
}
?>
```

But it seems your problem is with something else?

Comment: the code you did is working partially but I am getting this error: 'Notice: Undefined index: user_type in C:\wamp64\www\foldername\usermain.php'

Comment: means user_type isn't defined. you did do "select * from Users". assuming user_type is a column in in Users table, it should work...

Comment: Yes, user_type is in the column of the Users table and I includes the session_start(); in the login page, but I would continue to work on it.